# Make button disapper if hash changing during scroll

Tags: javascript

So, I'm using fullpage.js jquery for scrolling on my website. 
Each scroll section is divided in hashes, like index.html/#firstPage etc.
I've made a fixed scroll to top button, but I wanna make him disappear if hash equals #firstPage.
I've made a Js script too, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```js
mybutton = document.getElementById("scroll_top_button");

var stringHash = window.location.hash;
console.log(stringHash); // Returns hash and it works
function hashDisappear() {
  if (stringHash == "#firstPage") {// this thing doesn't work at all.
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

**Edit**
My bad, function was never called, but when hash changes, because of scrolling, button is not appearing, only after restart page. How to make it check if hash changes and execute function or smthing?

Comment: The function `hashDisappear` is never called?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm sorry, how can I call it? I thought it was enough to import script in html file...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#calling_functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
  //Your Function
}, false);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event

https://caniuse.com/?search=hashchange

Comment: Yes, but when i do console.log(stringHash); , even if hash changed, in console appears only hash that was after reload page. It's always #firstPage ( if script was loaded on the firstPage etc)

Answer (score -1):

I found perfect script for this situation

```css
mybutton = document.getElementById("scroll_top_button");

function locationHashChanged() {
  if (location.hash === "#firstPage") {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  }
}

window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

But @Smith Charl helped me to find main logic to do this script tho